# React Native Dark ToolBar theme

Tags: react-native

I want a light theme with a dark action bar.

I tried replacing

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
...
</style>
```

with

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
...
</style>
```

but it did not help.

Is it possible with react native?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the `DarkActionBar` theme to work either, however, the following worked for me:

```
<resources>
    <color name="primaryDark">#000</color>
    <color name="primary">#111</color>
    <color name="accent">#ffd400</color>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/primary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: It did not help for me :(

I want change color of right icon to white: http://oi65.tinypic.com/2ho9po8.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It seems this little fellow will do the trick:

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">some_color</item>
```